# Install nupkg from local nuget package

Tags: c#, nuget

I have followed http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingANuGetPackageIn7EasyStepsPlusUsingNuGetToIntegrateASPNETMVC3IntoExistingWebFormsApplications.aspx this guide to create my own nuget package. The only problem is when i use the console to install my package it just adds the cs files directly to the project instead of createing a .dll and add it as a package. The content folder of my nuget only contains two cs files is that why it doesn't create the package as a dll and instead just uses the cs files directly?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your original nuspec file for whether it's including the output DLLs or the raw CS's (probably the latter). Fix it and make sure the assemblies go into lib/netXX (e.g. lib/net45), not "content".

Also, the file is just a ZIP. Inspect it before you use it to ensure that it contains the right files.